# pe:sheet not triggering change for numeric values from null to 0

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

While using the PrimeFaces Sheet component I realized that for cells of type numeric change event is not triggered and also values are not submitted to server side when changing an empty(null) cell to the value 0.

For everything else it works as it is supposed to. Even if there already is value and then changing it to 0 also works ok. UI events are triggered correctly, I have hooks on the Handsontable component to onBeforeChange and onAfterChange and on the UI side the changes are registered.
I tried two approaches:

- One was without ajax change events, just submitting the form. In this case the values which are 0 are not submitted to the server side and they disappear from the UI as well.
- Second thing I tried is to have a ajax change event, which was not triggered in the case mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already reported against PFE 7.0 and fixed in 7.0.1.

See: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/681

Comment: Just a question, since I am stuck on PF 6.2.2 and PFE 6.2.10 is there any workaround for this issue in this version?

Comment: Yes you can use our updateSettings example and override `afterChange: function (change, source)` method and copy and paste the exact method from our current GIT which has the fix.  That will "plug in" this change. https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/sheet/1-sheet.js#L116-L145